# How to bind viewmodel to a gridView in android?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-gridview, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have a gridView in my activity with a custom adapter class, I cannot figure out how to bindview model to my activity's gridView.
Here is my gridview adapter:

```
class ImageAdapter constructor(val mContext: Context, private val resource_layout: Int, private val images: Array<Int>) :
    ArrayAdapter<ImageAdapter.ViewHolder>(mContext, resource_layout) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        var convertView = convertView
        val holder : ViewHolder

        if(convertView == null) {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(resource_layout, null)
            holder = ViewHolder()
            holder.imageItem = convertView.added_picture
            convertView.tag = holder
        } else {
            holder = convertView.tag as ViewHolder
        }

        Glide.with(mContext)
            .load("https://picsum.photos/200/300")
            .apply(RequestOptions.centerCropTransform())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_add_icon)
            .into(holder.imageItem)

        return convertView!!
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return images!!.size
    }

    inner class ViewHolder {
        lateinit var imageItem : ImageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take `<layout></layout>` inside your row file and you can set the variable name of your `ViewModel` name. Now you can set inflate your view in your `getViewHolder` in adapter as like below.

```
mTaskCustomLayoutBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.task_custom_layout, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(this!!.mTaskCustomLayoutBinding!!)
```

Set binding in your viewholder class

```
inner class MyViewHolder(val mBinding: TaskCustomLayoutBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(mBinding.getRoot())
```

So, you'll get the object of the binding and set the the data to your views.

Hope It'll help you :)

Comment: ok... I have uploaded my adapter code, what do I return from my viewholder?

Answer (score -1):

GridView grid = (GridView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.mGridView);

Comment: Na I was talking about viewmodel data binding